# How to prove $a\ln(1+x_1)+(1-a)\ln(1+x_2)\le \ln(1+x)$ for $a\in(0,1)$ and $x_1+x_2=x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convex-optimization, convexity-inequality

I am trying to prove an inequality that:

$a\ln(1+x_1)+(1-a)\ln(1+x_2)\le \ln(1+x)$

for $a\in(0,1)$ and $x_1+x_2=x$.
I am trying using the series expansion. But it looks complex. Is there any way I can use convexity or some property to prove this.

Comment: I think you are trying to solve this problem instead $a\ln(1+x_1)+(1-a)\ln(1+x_2)\le \ln(1+ax_1+(1-a)x_2)$ (convexity of $\ln(1+x)$)

Comment: i actually tried using calculator that the above inequality holds inequality if $x_1=x_2$. Otherwise the inequality holds true. But I am not able to prove that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x_1, x_2>0$. Since ln is concave, by Jensen's inequality,
\begin{align*}
a\ln (1+x_1) + (1-a)\ln(1+x_2) &\leq \ln (a(1+x_1) + (1-a)(1+x_2))\\
&= \ln(1+ax_1 + (1-a)x_2).
\end{align*}
Since ln is increasing, and $1+ax_1 + (1-a)x_2 \leq 1+x_1+x_2$ (this is where we need $x_1, x_2>0$), then
\begin{equation*}
\ln(1+ax_1+(1-a)x_2) \leq \ln(1+x_1+x_2) = \ln(1+x).
\end{equation*}

Comment: This is true only if $x_1, x_2 >0$. A counterexample is for $x_1=-1/2, x_2=0$ for which $ax_1+(1-a)x_2=-\frac{1}{2}a\geq x_1+x_2=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the inequality is not true for all $x_1+x_2=x$ in the domain.

For instance, with $x_1=x_2=-\frac13$ and $a = \frac 12$,

$$LHS = \frac12 \ln \frac23 + \frac12 \ln \frac23 > \ln \frac13 = RHS$$

Comment: Do you mean that $x$ has to be positive?

Comment: @hasan - $x$'s could be negative. You need $ax_2+(1-a)x_1 \ge 0$ for the inequality to hold.